# How to add Firebase Crashlytics into pakcage library?

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I have no issue in adding Firebase Crashlytics into main app via `File -> Add Package Dependencies...`

[image]

However, how about adding it to Package library?

[image]

I have a Package library, which contains shared code for multiple extensions.

I try to edit its `Package.swift` to

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "lib",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "lib",
            targets: ["lib"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.git", exact: "7.6.2"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk", exact: "9.6.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "lib",
            dependencies: ["Kingfisher", "firebase-ios-sdk"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "libTests",
            dependencies: ["lib"]),
    ]
)
```

But, my package library still not able to recognise the code

```
import FirebaseCrashlytics
```

May I know how I can resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `targets` `target` `dependencies` should look more like

```
    .target(
        name: "lib",
        dependencies: [
            .product(name:"FirebaseCrashlytics", package:"firebase-ios-sdk"),
            .product(name:"Kingfisher", package: "Kingfisher")
        ]
    ),
```

With the `product` being the specific part of Firebase that you want to use.

It is the equivalent of the screen you see after you click on "Add Package" from your first image.